# Is thunderbird key generation still secure?

Tags: thunderbird

I can't find much info in regards to the specifics of the PGP key generation involved in Thunderbird. The software is quite old and things like "This may take several minutes" or something while it taking less a second, are kinda making me raise an eyebrow.

While the software is being updated frequently, is the key generation algorithm still secure for it, as it doesn't matter how secure PGP if the key generation is weak and predictable.

Comment: The PGP code of Thunderbird is quite new, this was introduced last year with Thunderbird 78. Before there was only the old Enigmail plugin but that code was incompatible with the new Thunderbird base and the PGP code had to be written from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crypto.SE or Security.SE would be able to provide a much better-sourced answer than I do (I don't work on cryptography), but:

Regarding specific implementations, if you're using a recent Thunderbird with built-in OpenPGP support (which is actually quite new), most likely it was written to use the RSA keygen function that's provided by NSS, the SSL/TLS library used by Thunderbird and Firefox. That is to say, the operation is not actually PGP-specific, and the app only has to put the already-generated key in the correct envelope – it has no reason to be carrying some PGP-specific key generation code from decades ago.

*(Though even if it was, that doesn't mean the code hasn't been touched in decades, e.g. NSS itself with its Netscape roots is literally one of the oldest SSL libraries ever written.)*

On the other hand, it is, if I remember correctly, carrying the *user interface* code that used to be part of the Enigmail addon; they just integrated it into the app and replaced the backend. Some of the messages from early 2000s could quite possibly have remained.

But overall, there are a few reasons why it's fast:

1. A key generation algorithm isn't like password hashing algorithms; its strength **does not depend** on it being slow. Generating an RSA key just used to be slow because CPUs *were* slow and finding prime numbers actually took time. ​But both the random number generation and the various primality tests still achieve exactly the same thing at exactly the same level of security regardless of how long it takes.

   This does not vary much between different programs – you can test any tool that deals with RSA keys and they should give identical results. To use a slightly overkill key size as an example, something like `openssl genrsa 8192` (with OpenSSL) or `certtool -p --bits=8192` (GnuTLS) does take over a minute on a ~2005 Celeron CPU but only around 8 seconds on a ~2012 Xeon.

   *(OpenSSL is also "quite old", about as old as NSS, but it's used daily to create the vast majority of TLS certificates and their keypairs on the web.)*
2. Plain random number generators have actually gotten better (with new algorithms that are both faster *and* better-understood), but more importantly, they're also more readily available – in the past the program had to bring its own RNG and take care of collecting entropy from dubious sources (like "Entropy Gathering Daemon" in Unixes, or the "jiggle your mouse for 10 seconds" stuff that PuTTYgen still does today), nowadays each OS itself provides a CSPRNG that the application can instantly call for random data whenever needed.
3. We now have more widespread asymmetric key algorithms that aren't based around huge prime numbers at all – generating an ECDSA key, if you chose this option, is done in a completely different way than generating an RSA key and is, indeed, by design much faster than RSA. (The keys are much shorter at the same level security, too.)